# Trying to setup sort on a table using smart-table in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, smart-table

Using `angularjs` with [smart-table](http://lorenzofox3.github.io/smart-table-website/). Table headers are drawn but no data rows. Without `smart-table` data shows up fine. Any ideas?

error in console ..

```
"Error: [$compile:ctreq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.7/$compile/ctreq?p0=stTable&p1=stSort
```

dataset ..

```
[{
    "name": "Robert B",
        "associatedNumber": 21,
        "standing": true
}, {
    "name": "Martin C",
        "associatedNumber": 55,
        "standing": true
}, {
    "name": "Bobby B",
        "associatedNumber": 15,
        "standing": true
}]
```

`json` is returned by an api, `/players` ..

```
var app = angular.module('lmsHome', ['smart-table']);
app.controller('lmsHomeCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("/players").success(function (response) {
        $scope.players = response;
    });
});
```

html ..

```
<div ng-app="lmsHome" ng-controller="lmsHomeCtrl">
    <table class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th st-sort="name">Player</th>
                <th st-sort="associatedNumber">Number</th>
                <th st-sort="standing">Still standing?</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="player in players" ng-class="{'success': player.standing}">
                <td ng-cloak>
                    <span ng-show="player.standing">
                        {{player.name}}
                    </span>
                    <span ng-show="!player.standing">
                        <strike>{{player.name}}</strike>
                    </span>
                </td>
                <td ng-cloak>{{player.associatedNumber}}</td>
                <td ng-cloak>
                    <span class="label">{{player.standing}}</span>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- Angularjs -->
<script src="/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<!-- A table/grid for Angularjs -->
<script src="/table/smart-table.min.js"></script>
<!-- Custom logic -->
<script src="/js/homeLogic.js"></script>
```

Comment: following the link provided in the error, `Controller 'stTable', required by directive 'stSort', can't be found!`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://lorenzofox3.github.io/smart-table-website/#section-basics) for Smart Table, in order to use Smart Table,

> The first thing is to add the module `angular.module('myApp',['smart-table']` to your angular application. Then use the markup you would normally do for html tables. On the table element add the `st-table` attribute to tell smart-table which collection holds your **displayed data**, (ie the one you are going to use in the repeater). Now you will be able to compose the table using the plugins.

So it appears as you are missing the `st-table` attribute.

```html
<table class="table table-hover" st-table="players">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th st-sort="name">Player</th>
      <th st-sort="associatedNumber">Number</th>
      <th st-sort="standing">Still standing?</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="player in players" ng-class="{'success': player.standing}">
      ...
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: this removes the error and my data is populated into table, but now when i click a table header all data disappears.

Comment: @bobbyrne01 I don't really know why that would occur, that sounds like a different question.  I don't use Smart Table or participate in it's development, I was simply looking up the error you posted and providing documentation to solve it.